# Phpmyadmin loading html codes instead of the normal page

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I installed Apache2, MySQL and phpmyadmin in my Ubuntu OS version 20.04
But on trying to access my phpmyadmin page,l using localhost/phpmyadmin... I'm loads a raw codes instead of the regular page.

Having uninstalled phpmyadmin and reinstalled, issue still persists..
Also tried using some answers I got on StackOver yet it doesn't solve it.

Comment: make sure PHP is installed and enabled in apache handler (e.g. AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5) in the httpd.conf

Answer (score -1):

change index.php of PHPMyAdmin folder to 0644 or add execute permission to that

```
chmod 644 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php
```

or

```
chmod +x /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php
```